# Object follow the path in two points

Tags: animation, path

I need to animate sliding gate following the path in two points where the wheels touch the rail. The rail is not straight.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118295/discussion-on-question-by-igor-object-follow-the-path-in-two-points).